# QLineEdit in QDialog does not show the text that is typed in it

Tags: qt, qdialog, qlineedit

I am developing an application in QT For Symbian 3. I have a QDialog that takes text input from user. Everything works fine except that the text entered in QLineEdit cannot be seen. The text is there but it is not visible. I used update() and setText() and even styling but it doesn't have any effect? Can anyone please help me??

Comment: Does your cursor move along the line edit as you type? In that case it could just be that the line edit's text color is the same as its background?

Answer (score 0):

So there is no text display, but when you do this: `your_line_edit->text();` there is really the text you have entered?

The only solution I can come up with is to do this:

```
your_line_edit->setEchoMode( QLineEdit::Normal );
```

Let me know if that works.

Comment: this shouldn't work, because QLineEdit::Normal is the default

Comment: No. `text()` returns the default text set with `setText()` or empty if none set